# Preserve Autoincrement ID Within MySQL Transaction

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I have two MySQL database tables that are meant to hold data for eshop orders. They're built as such (extremely simplified version):

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `order_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `orderID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
```

The relationship between the two is that orders.id corresponds to order_items.orderID.

I'm using a transaction to place a new order, however have a problem preserving the above relationship. In order to get the new order id. I have to commit the orders INSERT query, get the autoincremented id and then start another transaction for the order items. Which pretty much defeats the point of using transactions.

I could insert the new order in the orders table and then try something like

```
INSERT INTO order_items(orderID) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID())
```

which I assume would work. However after the first order item is inserted `LAST_INSERT_ID()` would stop returning the order id and instead return the order item id making it impossible to use this query to insert another order item.

Is there a way to make this whole thing work within a single transaction or should I give up and use a procedure instead?

Comment: this is wrong: "I have to commit the orders INSERT query, get the autoincremented id and then start another transaction for the order items". i see this all the time here on stackoverflow. where did you learn this?

Comment: @longneck I think you misunderstood. That was me explaining the process I don't want to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WOuld this work?:

```
INSER QUERY;
SET @insertid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO `order_items` SET `OrderID` = @insertid;
```

All in one statement. You will have to double check the syntax

Comment: or get the value of LAST_INSERT_ID() in your application, and build the insert for order_items there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't count on LAST_INSERT_ID() because it also changes when you insert values to order_items because it inserts its id which is also auto_imcrement.
Maybe you can try this.

```
INSERT INTO order_items(orderID) VALUES((SELECT id FROM orders ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1))
```

Comment: what you have proposed creates a race condition. if two people insert orders at the same time, one of them will get the wrong id.